# Return Unique values without overlap

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a transaction database, and I need to compare to two tables for mismatches

I do not have a enough values to prevent overlapping results:

Here is my SQL Code

```
USE DB
SELECT DISTINCT T1.loan_Account, T1.Payment_Received, T1.Pay_Amount AS Pending
    , T2.Pay_Amount AS CheckRegister
FROM [PendingToPay] T1, [CheckRegister] T2
WHERE T1.loan_Account = T2.Loan_Account 
AND T1.Payment_Received = T2.Received
ORDER BY T1.Payment_Received
```

How do filter out results like this?

```
LALUZ   2020-02-20 00:00:00.0000000 25.00   25.00
LALUZ   2020-02-20 00:00:00.0000000 25.00   27.12
LALUZ   2020-02-20 00:00:00.0000000 25.00   1149.98
LALUZ   2020-02-20 00:00:00.0000000 27.12   25.00
LALUZ   2020-02-20 00:00:00.0000000 27.12   27.12
LALUZ   2020-02-20 00:00:00.0000000 27.12   1149.98
LALUZ   2020-02-20 00:00:00.0000000 1149.98 25.00
LALUZ   2020-02-20 00:00:00.0000000 1149.98 27.12
LALUZ   2020-02-20 00:00:00.0000000 1149.98 1149.98
```

Comment: Can you provide original data before your expected result?

Comment: BTW its best practice to use proper join syntax.

Comment: got it thanks! for the feedback sorry new to forums

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you need to check if pay_amount in both tables is not equal.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
T1.loan_Account,
T1.Payment_Received, 
T1.Pay_Amount as Pending, 
T2.Pay_Amount as CheckRegister
FROM [PendingToPay] T1
JOIN [CheckRegister] T2 ON T1.loan_Account=T2.Loan_Account  
                       AND T1.Payment_Received = T2.Received
WHERE T1.Pay_Amount <> T2.Pay_Amount
ORDER BY T1.Payment_Received
```

You can also summarize each account's payments for a day using group by instead of printing multiple results. Off course if you are only interested in mismatch on a daily basis than the individual transactions of mismatch.

```
SELECT T1.loan_Account,
  CAST(T1.Payment_Received as DATE) as Payment_Received, 
   SUM(T1.Pay_Amount) as Pending, 
   SUM(T2.Pay_Amount) as CheckRegister
FROM [PendingToPay] T1
JOIN [CheckRegister] T2 ON T1.loan_Account=T2.Loan_Account  
                       AND T1.Payment_Received = T2.Received
GROUP BY T1.loan_Account,CAST(T1.Payment_Received as DATE)
HAVING SUM(T1.Pay_Amount) <> SUM(T2.Pay_Amount)
ORDER BY T1.Payment_Received
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
USE DB; 
SELECT DISTINCT
    T1.loan_Account, 
    T1.Payment_Received, 
    T1.Pay_Amount AS Pending, 
    T2.Pay_Amount AS CheckRegister,
    IIF(T1.Pay_Amount <> T2.Pay_Amount, 'YES', 'NO') [Mismatches]
FROM [PendingToPay] T1
    LEFT JOIN [CheckRegister] T2 ON T1.loan_Account = T2.Loan_Account 
        AND T1.Payment_Received = T2.Received
ORDER BY T1.Payment_Received
```